# symfony translation in Mysql

Tags: mysql, internationalization, symfony1

I would like to configure Symfony to get Translation from Mysql and not from XLIFF files.

I see explaination on this page : http://www.symfony-project.org/reference/1_4/en/05-Factories#chapter_05_i18n

I configure the factories.yml:

```
  i18n:
    class: sfI18N
    param:
      source: MySQL
```

And I get this error:
500 | Internal Server Error | sfException
Error in connecting to Array.

I think I should configure which database but I don't know how to do it with doctrine.

Can anyone help me ? :)

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not work" ? any error messages ? pieces of source code with your attempts ?
As well please accept more answers for your previous questions...

Comment: yes, sorry, I edit my question

Answer (score 3):

It is described here:

http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/13-I18n-and-L10n

jump to section "Text Information in the Database".

Quick description:

1. create your table like "tablename"
2. create the translation table "tablename_i18n" like:

   - id
   - culture
   - name ( <= this is what you want to translate)

Now generate the model and it will automatically generate the getName() method against the Tablename object, but it's gonna have a parameter the culture.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I do not need to translate model but string. I want to store strings from __() method into the database.

Comment: okay, then here you go check out this: http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/tags/RELEASE_1_4_10/lib/i18n/sfMessageSource_MySQL.class.php in the comment there is how to configure it

Comment: so I just need to define the table catalogue and trans_unit and it should work ? I will try it thanks :)

Comment: This functionality is not documented in the symfony docs, so just have a look at that file, the comment looks like a full description about how it is working. Also look through the source code.